# C how to convert between a normal char to unsigned char (uint)?

Tags: c, string, char

I'm fiddling around with a set of i2c addresses from a file.
The i2c addresses are all unsigned chars and looks like '0x20' or '0x27'.

The problem is when reading from the file i get an array of char, and i cant figure out
how to convert the char[] "0x21" to the unsigned char '0x21'.

is there something similar to `printf("0x%02x", address[i]);` but works in the other direction?

Comment: Q: What do you mean by "convert"?  A "char" and an "unsigned char" have *EXACTLY THE SAME BITS* - there's no "conversion" required.  Perhaps you mean [cast](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm)?  EXAMPLE: `printf("0x%02x", (unsigned char)address[i]);`

Comment: Sorry, my misstake. Yes i mean cast not convert. If i init i2c with unsigned char 0x21, everything works, but if i try to initialize with normal char[] it segfaults.

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked. Is it a text file or a binary file? What is the *exact* file content? How are you reading it? Why don't you read it into an array of `unsigned char` if that is what you want?

Comment: *`if i try to initialize with normal char[] it segfaults.`*  - `char[]` is not `char` ,

Comment: How to? Start from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @WeatherVane the file is a normal textfile containing standard ascii chars. i use  fopen(filname, "r");

Answer (score 1):

The question is basically: "How do I interpret a string as an unsigned char value?"

The [C standard library header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) has several functions for these types of conversions, all named "strto*". The closest match for what you want to do is `strtoul` (string to unsigned long). The `unsigned long` can be cast to an unsigned char. Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "0x21";

    unsigned char uc = (unsigned char) strtoul(str, NULL, 16);
    printf("%u\n", uc);
}
```

Which prints "33".

Comment: yes, that is my exact problem, i need it to be 0x21 not 31 :/

Comment: Do you mean 33? "0x21" and "33" are two different _representations_ of the same value. One is base 16 and the other one is base 10. In other words, `unsigned char a = 0x21;` has exactly the same effect as `unsigned char a = 33;`.

Comment: ...which can be seen from `printf("%u 0x%x\n", uc, uc);` which outputs `33 0x21`